# Expressjs Sync/Asynchronous Middleware Issues -- How to fix?

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js, jsonschema, ajv

I have an Expressjs route which does a db INSERT (using Sequelize) based on some JSON Body params in the request. The `bodyParser` middleware does a JSON-schema validation on the body and returns an error if it doesn't validate.

The issue here is that something in `bodyparser` is executing asynchronously, and I'm getting errors such as null values being inserted into the DB (even after a failed validation), and `Headers already returned to client` errors.

How to best fix this?

The route:

```
var bodyParser = json_validator.with_schema('searchterm');
router.post('/', bodyParser, function (req, res, next) {
    Searchterm.findOrCreate({
        where: {searchstring: req.body.searchstring},
        defaults: {funnystory: req.body.funnystory},
        attributes: ['id', 'searchstring', 'funnystory']
    }).spread((searchterm, created) => {
        if (created) {
            res.json(searchterm);
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(409);
        }
    }).catch(next);
});
```

The middleware:

```
var ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json({type: '*/json'});

module.exports.with_schema = function(model_name) {
    let schemafile = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'models', 'schemas', model_name + '.schema.yaml');
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(schemafile);
    let schema = yaml.safeLoad(rawdata);
    var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
    return function(req, res, next) {
        jsonParser(req, res, next);
        if (!validate(req.body)) {
            res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({"errors": validate.errors}));
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middleware calls `next` too early; change:

```
return function(req, res, next) {
    jsonParser(req, res, next);
    if (!validate(req.body)) {
        res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({"errors": validate.errors}));
    }
}
```

to:

```
return function(req, res, next) {
    if (!validate(req.body)) {
        res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({"errors": validate.errors}));
    }
}
```

and your route definition to:

```
router.post('/', jsonParser, bodyParser, function (req, res, next) { ... });
```